# How do you invoke an alternative static constructor in Java?

Tags: java, constructor, static

How do you call these alternative static constructors in Java?

I want to create a Location object using the newFromLatLong format and do not know how to

```
public class Location {

    public final double x;
    public final double y;

    public Location(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public static Location newFromPoint(Point point, Location origin,
            double scale) {
        return new Location(point.x / scale + origin.x, origin.y - point.y
                / scale);
    }

    
    public static Location newFromLatLon(double lat, double lon) {
        double y = (lat - CENTRE_LAT) * SCALE_LAT;
        double x = (lon - CENTRE_LON)
                * (SCALE_LAT * Math.cos((lat - CENTRE_LAT) * DEG_TO_RAD));
        return new Location(x, y);
    }
```

Comment: These are class methods and you call them just like any other class method.

Comment: Do I have to use them upon a existing Location? Why do they look like Constructors like so?

Comment: These static methods are not constructors(constructors are non-static and does not have return type). These method create new object. They can be invoked as `Location location = Location.newFromLocation(lat, lon)`

Comment: The term, by the way, is _static builder method_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have static methods to create an object, so you call them on the class itself, which will return you a `Location` object. You can use it for further uses.

```
Location location = Location.newFromLatLon(1.1, 1.2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider use a builder pattern to create your Location object. To avoid duplicate code, I recommend to use Lombok `@Builder` annotation:

https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder

Also, consider you are using the same `Location` object as parameter for the `newFromPoint` method:

```java
public static Location newFromPoint(Point point, Location origin,
            double scale) {
        return new Location(point.x / scale + origin.x, origin.y - point.y
                / scale);
}
```

Maybe you will need to take a look to your domain definition.